# How to get SPUser from FBA login name

Tags: 2010, forms-authentication, spuser

I have a Form Based Authentication login name `login_name`

how to get an `SPUser` object for that login name.

I have tried the

```
Web.EnsureUser(string.Format("c:0-.f|role|{0}", name));
```

but it gives me that the name was not found exception.

Comment: change 'role' for the name of your membership provider.

Comment: My comment above will probably resolve your immediate requirement, but I also have a similar requirement for getting an SPUser for a username from a claim that can be from any issuer (forms, windows, trusted IP), so if someone has a more complete answer, I'd be grateful, too :)